# Form async-validator not rendering

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to make a simple [form](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-normal-login).

I am able to get all valid data if they are inputted and receive errors on the console, if they are not:

> async-validator: ["username is required"]
>
> async-validator: ["passwordis required"]

But the errors are not rendering.

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/0c41ec308f944cd67eb6d1a94639ac96.png]

Parent

```
const HomePage = () => (
  <Layout className="layout" style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}>
    <Header>Teste</Header>
    <Content className={_s.Content}>
      <LoginForm />
    </Content>
    <Footer style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>React Node Boilerplate by Igor Cesar</Footer>
  </Layout>
);

export default HomePage;
```

Form

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;

    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className={_s.loginForm}>
        <Form.Item>
          {getFieldDecorator('username', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }]
          })(
            <Input
              prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />}
              placeholder="Username"
            />
          )}
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item>
          {getFieldDecorator('password', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!' }]
          })(
            <Input
              prefix={<Icon type="lock" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />}
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
            />
          )}
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item>
          {getFieldDecorator('remember', {
            valuePropName: 'checked',
            initialValue: true
          })(<Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>)}
          <a className={_s.loginFormForgot} href="/">
            Forgot password
          </a>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" className={_s.loginFormButton}>
            Log in
          </Button>
          Or <a href="/">register now!</a>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

const WrapperLoginForm = Form.create()(LoginForm);

export default WrapperLoginForm;
```

Comment: The code is ok, the problem is within your CSS, try deleting the `className`s and see that it works fine. Moreover, welcome to StackOverflow, please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to  [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It much easier for people to help you when they got a code to play with, try to upload a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/pww70x7y6q

Comment: I cant replicate it on sandbox, i think maybe is something to do with webpack or babel. I removed css, even tried to put form in root file for minimal interference. Still have the same problem. My repo is here: https://github.com/IgorMCesar/react-node-boilerplate

Comment: You can import a github project to the sandbox... Do you understand that your question is too abroad? You need to add a minimal example of the bug, otherwise, there is a low chance that someone will literally go over your project and look for the bug.

Comment: Thanks for your patience Dennis, I didnt know it was possivel to import a git repo to sandbox. Sorry if the question is too abroad, i never encontered a problem like this, i literraly cant even pinpoint a possible cause... Here is the sandbox, maybe this is a little better :/ https://codesandbox.io/s/github/IgorMCesar/react-node-boilerplate

Answer (score 1):

**In order to help people who will reach this page in the future:**

The author [reported the bug to antdesign](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/17622) and a solution was found.

This was a problem with `lodash-webpack-plugin`, and the required change is in **webpack.config.js**. Turns out `LodashModuleReplacementPlugin()` should receive `{paths: true}` as a parameter, and the problem's gone.

```js
module.exports = {
    //... rest of your webpack config
    plugins: [
        //... rest of your plugins
        new LodashModuleReplacementPlugin({paths: true}),
    ],
}
```